# Powershell shortcut creation isn't working

Tags: windows, powershell

So I have this script that is automating the installation of some software. After I install the software, I create shortcuts to some important applications these shortcuts appear on the desktop. Here is my code.

```
$ConfigureExeSource = "C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteKiosk\Configure.exe"
$ConfigureLoc = "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Configure.lnk"

$StartSiteKioskExeSource = "C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteKiosk\SiteKiosk.exe"
$StartSiteKioskLoc = "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\SiteKiosk.lnk"

$CheckKioskExeSource = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\checkkiosk.exe"
$CheckKioskLoc = "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\checkkiosk.lnk"

#copying to desktop
$WshShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut($ConfigureLoc)
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $ConfigureExeSource
$Shortcut.Save()
Write-Host "Created Configure.exe Shortcut"

$WshShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut($StartSiteKioskLoc)
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $StartSiteKioskExeSource
$Shortcut.Save()
Write-Host "Created Sitekiosk.exe Shortcut"

$WshShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut($CheckKioskLoc)
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $CheckKioskExeSource
$Shortcut.Save()
Write-Host "Created Checkkiosk.exe Shortcut"
```

I then get the shortcuts generated, After that I tested each one. This resulted in all of them working except the Configure shortcut.

I manually created a configure shortcut to make sure I had the right path and I did. I then compared other properties and I found that the startIn Property was blank for my powershell one but filled with "C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteKiosk" in the manually created one. I copied that over to the powershell one and it worked.

Now I have no Idea whats going on because the sitekiosk shortcut worked without the field filled in but the configure one wants it for some reason or else it won't work. does anyone know how I could fix my code to properly generate a shortcut that works, even if the fix just generates that field for the shortcut. I've looked around and haven't found a way to fill the startIn field in a shortcut.

PS: I tried uploading photos but stackoverflow didn't let me as I have below 10 rep, I can upload them to imgur though if anyone thinks it would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen in the [MSDN reference page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xk6kst2k(v=vs.84).aspx) you would want to set the WorkingDirectory property.

```
$WshShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut($ConfigureLoc)
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $ConfigureExeSource
$Shortcut.WorkingDirectory = "C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteKiosk"
$Shortcut.Save()
```