# Shortcut (.lnk) with Powershell - why does it not work

Tags: powershell, shortcut

(OK - I still get one error)

Why in heavens is this happening? All I need to do is execute [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26876832/powershell-shortcut-creation-isnt-working) in one line.
Like this:

```
PS C:\Users\Horn.Ruben> $shell = New-Object -com "WScript.Shell"; $TestBackupAddin = $shell.CreateShortcut("C:\ClusterStorage\Volume2\test.lnk"); $TetsBackupAddin.TargetPath = "C:\ClusterStorage\Volume2\_VMBackups\20150113-0844\TestBackupAddin"; $TestBackupAddin.Save();
```

Now the only error that I get is this:

```
The property 'TargetPath' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:1 char:123
+ $shell = New-Object -com "WScript.Shell"; $TestBackupAddin = $shell.CreateShortc ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
```

Do both directories need to exist before I can use this?

PS: I need all of this to run in one line (with multiple shortcuts created later)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$TestBackupAddin = $shell.CreateShortcut
```

instead of

```
$TetsBackupAddin = $shell.CreateShortcut
```

Comment: Note to self: Don't drink, go home late, get up for work before 5:00 am and expect your brain to work :P

Comment: @RUB3N Using the strict mode, [Set-StrictMode](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849692.aspx), will catch such an error by complaining about non-existing variable.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$shell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
```

Instead of

```
$shell = New-Object -ComObjetct WScript.Shell
```

Comment: -> updated the question. Still doesn't work